# Subtract percentage in C#

Tags: c#, percentage, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract percentage in C# using:

```
n = n - (n * 0.25);
```

but I'm getting an error:

> "Cannot implicitly 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversions exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: where is the percentage?

Comment: @Jon - The question is obviously "what am I doing wrong?"

Comment: Do you expect a 25% of an int always to be an `int` ?

Comment: @Ergwun: Obviously. But stating it explicitly allows the OP an opportunity to reason about it themselves (rubber duck debugging) and also allows us to give more relevant answers. I 'm not asking just in order to be obtuse.

Comment: if the percentage is always 25% go for n = n - (n >> 2); saves you the integer to float to integer conversion :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your value `n` is an `int`.

When you multiply by `0.25`( which is a `double`), the resulting value is a `double` that you try to assign to a `int`.

To solve it, you have to specify that you are aware that you will lose precision using "explicit conversion".

```
n = n - (int)(n * 0.25);
```

Doing `(Type)value` is called "to cast `value` to `Type`". This is exactly what the error message suggest you to do.

Or, if you don't want to keep the precision, declare `n` not as an `int` but as a `double`. In this case, you will not have to cast `n * 0.25` to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to switch back and forwards between int and double types you could just use:

n = (n * 75) / 100

if your answer ever has decimals they'll be lost though

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `n` must be an integer, but the result of your calculation is a double, since it involves multiplication by a double (`0.25`).

You can cast the result back to an int like this:

```
n = (int)(n - (n * 0.25));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `n` is an integer type then, say `int`, as you don't give a clue to that. In which case the easiest solution is to do:

```
n = Convert.ToInt32(n - (n * 0.25));
```

Or you can cast:

```
n = (int)(n - (n * 0.25));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of variable 'n'.

Either 'n' should be of double type.

Or

Use explicit cast to convert to int.

```
int n = (int)(n - (n * 0.25));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `n` variable is an `int`. When you try to multiple with `0.25`, `0.25` is `double`, so result will be `double`. You should cast it manually because there is no [`Implicit Numeric Conversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) for `double` to `int`. You have to use [`Explicit Numeric Conversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx) for them.

```
From --> To

double --> sbyte , byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, or decimal
```

You should convert your right expression to `int`.

```
int n = 100;
n = (int) (n - (n * 0.25));
Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/7h5F8B).

And remember;

- Explicit numeric conversion may cause loss of precision.
- When you convert from a `double` value to an integral type, the value is truncated. If the resulting integral value is outside the range of the destination value, the result depends on the overflow checking context.

Answer (score 0):

you must cast result to int

```
n=(int)(n-(n*0.25));
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
n = n - (int)((double)n * 0.25);
```

note: by doing this you wont have numbers behind the point in the n result.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be an issue with the type of n being `int` it least needs to be `double`

hence when you have `n = n - (n * 0.25)` the result is a double

if you want to cast it as int then **beware of rounding** since it would not always be ending in `.00`

Also i think this would be better `n = n * 0.75`

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to do

```
 n = n - n/4;
```

If you want a percentage to be a whole number between 0 and 100, otherwise you should declare `n` to be a `double` by replacing `int n` with `double n`.
No costly conversion will occur in the proposed assignment. Note that `n/4` is an integer because both operands (`n` and `4`) are integers, causing no promotions, thus using integer division.

**Explanation**

This is type promotion, `n` is multiplied by a `double`, which promotes `n*0.25` automatically to a `double`. A primitive can only be promoted into a higher rank, not demoted to a lower rank. A primitive `x` is of a higher rank then another primitive `y` if it can hold all values of `y` without causing loss of precision. A `double` can hold all values of an integer, but an integer can, for example, not hold `0.1`. So you are trying to promote and demote. See [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) for more information.

Note:
Casting from a `double` to an `int` causes the value to be truncated, that is all decimals after the 'dot' will be erased, so `-2.5` becomes `-2` and `1.5` becomes `1`. Integer division, as used above also rounds to zero, making this assignment equal with your assignment. But avoiding any costly conversions.